# How to save and retrieve a fingerprint template in phpmyadmin database, using VB

Tags: vb.net, phpmyadmin, fingerprint, biometrics

We are using digital persona for our biometrics. We can already save employee ID, employee name and assigned finger .Our problem is that we dont know how to save a fingerprint template to a database and retrieve it so that it can still be read and verified by the biometric scanner. The file extension is ".ftp" .

CODE:

```
Private Sub buttonRegister_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles buttonRegister.Click

        'Does user already exists
        Dim bUserExists As Boolean = _Users.UserExists(New UserID(textBoxUserName.Text))

        ' first make sure the user is created if new user
        If _ActiveUser Is Nothing Or Not bUserExists Then
            ' initialize with supplied user name
            _ActiveUser = New User(textBoxUserName.Text)
        Else
            ' update active user if not as originally selected
            If bUserExists And Not listBoxUsers.SelectedItem.ToString() = textBoxUserName.Text Then
                _ActiveUser = _Users(New UserID(textBoxUserName.Text))
            End If
        End If

        ' and check if the template already exists for the assigned finger
        If _ActiveUser.TemplateExists(_AssignedFinger) Then
            ' show message indicating template already exists for selected finger
            Dim diagResult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(Me, [String].Format("Oops!" + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Lf + "{0} has a template enrolled to his/her {1} finger." + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Lf + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Lf + "Shall the old template be discarded?", _ActiveUser.ID.ToString(), _Fingers(_AssignedFinger)), "Template already assigned!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            ' if user selected not to overwrite, then abort
            If diagResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
                Return
            End If
        End If

        Try
            ' attempt to read the template
            Dim templateOpened As New DPFP.Template(File.OpenRead(textBoxTemplateFilename.Text))

            ' run a template duplicate check
            IdentifyTemplate(templateOpened)

            ' remove the old template if exists
            If _ActiveUser.TemplateExists(_AssignedFinger) Then
                ' removed from assigned finger
                _ActiveUser.RemoveTemplate(_AssignedFinger)
            End If

            ' and assign it to the user as specified
            _ActiveUser.AddTemplate(templateOpened, _AssignedFinger)

            ' update collection
            If Not _Users.UserExists(_ActiveUser.ID) Then
                ' update list box
                listBoxUsers.Items.Add(_ActiveUser.ID.ToString())

                ' add user it to the user collection
                _Users.AddUser(_ActiveUser)
            End If

            ' success
            UpdateEventLog([String].Format("{0}: Template successfully assigned to {1} finger.", _ActiveUser.ID.ToString(), _AssignedFinger.ToString()))

            ' turn off groupbox
            groupAddTemplate.Visible = False

            listBoxUsers.SelectedItem = _ActiveUser.ID.ToString()

            ' sync gui
            _syncUI()

            ' view user
            _syncViewUser()

        Catch Err As DPFP.Error.SDKException
            ' log message
            UpdateEventLog(Err.ToString())
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(Err.ToString())
        Catch Err As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
            ' log message
            UpdateEventLog("Template file not found or is inaccessible.")
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(Err.ToString())
        Catch Err As Exception
            ' log message
            UpdateEventLog(Err.ToString())
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(Err.ToString())
        End Try

        Using conn As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database = vb")
            Using cmd
                With cmd
                    MsgBox("Connection Established")
                    .Connection = conn
                    .Parameters.Clear()
                    'Create Insert Query
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO employees(UserID, Name, Finger) VALUES (@iID, @iName, @iFinger)"
                    .Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@iID", ID.Text))
                    .Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@iName", textBoxUserName.Text))
                    .Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@iFinger", comboBoxAssignedFinger.Text))


                End With
                Try
                    'Open Connection and Execute Query
                    conn.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As MySqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

i know that this is an old post but here are code blocks that might help...

IN SAVING I USED THIS

```
       For Each template As DPFP.Template In Data.Templates    
            If Not template Is Nothing Then 
                cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO employeefp " +
                                  "SET No=@No, " +
                                  "FP=@FP " +
                                  " ", conn)

                cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@No", txtEmpNo.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@FP", template.Bytes))

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End If
        Next
```

IN VERIFYING FROM THE DB I USED THIS

1. WHEN FORM IS LOADED I FETCH ALL THE FINGER PRINTS

   ```
       Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employeefp  ", conn)
       Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

       While (rdr.Read())
           Dim MemStream As IO.MemoryStream
           Dim fpBytes As Byte()

           fpBytes = rdr("FP")
           MemStream = New IO.MemoryStream(fpBytes)

           Dim templa8 As DPFP.Template = New DPFP.Template()
           templa8.DeSerialize(MemStream)

           Dim tmpObj As New AppData
           tmpObj.No = rdr("No").ToString()
           tmpObj.Template = templa8
           FPList.Add(tmpObj)
       End While
   ```

NOTE : Dim FPList As List(Of AppData) = New List(Of AppData) //you can find the definition of this in the SDK i just added Template (contains one print) aside from the existing Templates(contains many print)

1. COMPARE THE CURRENT SAMPLE FROM THE MACHINE

   ```
   Sub OnComplete(ByVal Control As Object, ByVal FeatureSet As DPFP.FeatureSet, ByRef EventHandlerStatus As DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus) Handles VerificationControl.OnComplete
   Dim printFound As Boolean = False
   VerifiedFPData = New AppData
   Try
       For Each FPData As AppData In FPList
           Dim tmplateData As New DPFP.Template
           tmplateData = FPData.Template
           Dim compareTo As New DPFP.FeatureSet
           compareTo = FeatureSet

           Dim ver As New DPFP.Verification.Verification()
           Dim res As New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()

           If Not tmplateData Is Nothing Then
               ver.Verify(FeatureSet, tmplateData, res)

               If res.Verified Then
                   EventHandlerStatus = DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus.Success
                   printFound = True
                   VerifiedFPData = FPData
                   Exit For ' success
               End If
           End If
       Next
   Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show("verification error")
   End Try


   If printFound Then
       //TO DO 
   Else
       EventHandlerStatus = DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus.Failure
       // TODO
   End If
   ```

   End Sub

hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some missing codes from the answer above. The code of the class appdata is missing.These code is error without declaring first the tmpObj in the class AppData. `Dim tmpObj As New AppData
        tmpObj.No = rdr("No").ToString()
        tmpObj.Template = templa8
        FPList.Add(tmpObj)`